# Find element in nested json using json_extrct

Tags: mysql, json

I have json which looks like

```
[
  {
"processor": "VISA",
"mapping": {
  "VSID": "161521582"
 }
 },
{
"processor": "MC",
"mapping": {
  "authAcquirerMID": "720000046943001",
  "authAcquirerICA": "3286"
}
},
{
"processor": "MC",
"mapping": {
  "LocationId": "305901891"
}
},
{
"processor": "VISA",
"mapping": {
  "VSID": "72002961"
}
]
```

I have to get the valuses of VSID for both "processor": "VISA"? How will I do that? 
For now I have tried

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[{"processor":"VISA","mapping":{"VSID":"161521582"}},
{"processor":"MC","mapping":{"authAcquirerMID":"720000046943001","authAcquirerICA":"3286"}},
{"processor":"MC","mapping":{"LocationId":"305901891"}},
{"processor":"MC","mapping":{"authAcquirerMID":"720000046943001","authAcquirerICA":"003286"}},
{"processor":"VISA","mapping":{"VSID":"72002961"}},
{"processor":"AMEX","mapping":{"targetingId":"1045006731"}}]',
'$.mapping.VSID');
```

but it doesn't give any results.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the values here are fine to be exposed to the whole web to see ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the wildcard operator to find it in all arrays like

```
'$[*].mapping.VSID'
```

**sample**

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(
'[{"processor":"VISA","mapping":{"VSID":"161521582"}},
{"processor":"MC","mapping":{"authAcquirerMID":"720000046943001","authAcquirerICA":"3286"}},
{"processor":"MC","mapping":{"LocationId":"305901891"}},
{"processor":"MC","mapping":{"authAcquirerMID":"720000046943001","authAcquirerICA":"003286"}},
{"processor":"VISA","mapping":{"VSID":"72002961"}},
{"processor":"AMEX","mapping":{"targetingId":"1045006731"}}]'
,'$[*].mapping.VSID')) as result;

["161521582", "72002961"]
```